# How can I connect to mysql database which is on the server locally?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, ubuntu, remote-access

I've imported my databases on the server and I want to access them locally. The problem is I cannot. I mean the server doesn't response to my request.

I've added `root` to having access to "mydb" user list and I've given *(granted)* all privileges to it. Also I've commented `bind_address` in `my.conf` file and then I've restarted the mysql.

Still when I run this command:

```
telnet <ip> 3306
```

No response received.

Any idea how can I make a connection between my local and the database on the server?

---

#### MyTests:

- [`sudo netstat -plnt`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtGw5.png)
- [`tcpdump port 3306`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXgd3.png)
- [`sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 3306`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oB6H.png)

Comment: DId you create a user that is allowed to connect from a remote domain?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes, I use `root` and I've granted all priviliges to it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Can you please take a look at my server if I give you the id and username and password of it?

Comment: Try https://serverfault.com/a/586656/783 (so, do *not* comment the  bind_address line) Are you in an ubuntu VM on Windows host?

Comment: @VonC No there isnot any VMware. ubuntu is installed on the server, and I use windows 10 on my local (which I want to connect to the server from local)

Comment: @VonC Also I've tried your solution *(using `0.0.0.0` as the value of `bind_address` instead of commenting it)*. But sadly the same error exists.

Comment: Is it a firewall issue? (meaning the outbound query at the Windows side would be blocked) http://www.collectionsmax.com/help/installationguide/open_firewall_ports_print.htm

Comment: @VonC Hmm .. not sure, but yes, it can be the problem.

Comment: @VonC Well now I have to do something on the server or on my local?

Comment: On Windows side, to check if the query is blocked by the firewall.

Comment: @VonC Well I think this is not the problem. Since I can connect to mysql databases which are on the other server as well by this same computer. So the problem is somewhere on server side.

Comment: @VonC Well I give up. I've spent lots of my time to fix this annoying problem, but it's still there. I've even tried to uninstall and reinstall MySQL again, but it doesn't even get uninstall. You know, I'm not very familiar with command line environment. Can you *please* take a look at it if I give you the user and password of the server? *(please man, I really have no more time to devote for this problem)*

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Being quite busy at the moment (not to mention at work), I won't be able to take a look though.

Comment: @VonC Ah ok. I will keep working on the problem, and I will ask it again from you the other time if the problem doesn't fix.